# Why doesn't this TCP server work?

Tags: haskell

I wrote this simple tcp server:

```
import Network
import Network.Socket.ByteString

main :: IO()
main = do
    sock <- listenOn $ PortNumber 2000
    contents <- recv sock 4096
    print contents
```

Stack built successfully, so then I ran the server, using telnet to test it, but I got an error:

On linux:

```
Network.Socket.recvBuf:invalid argument (Transport endpoint is not connected)
```

On windows:

```
Network.Socket.recvBuf:failed(No error)
```

What's wrong with the program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`listenOn` just creates a "listen socket" which "listen" new connections to your server. You should to use the `accept` function to obtain new clients, like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    sock <- listenOn $ PortNumber 2000
    (client, _, _) <- accept sock
    contents <- hGetContents client
    print contents
    sClose sock
```

Or use lowlevel the `accept` function (from the `Network.Socket` module) to obtain socket:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    sock <- listenOn $ PortNumber 2000
    (client, _) <- accept sock
    contents <- recv client 4096
    print contents
    sClose client
    sClose sock
```

If you want to handle more clients you can use `forkIO` like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    sock <- listenOn $ PortNumber 2000
    forever $ do
        (client, _) <- accept sock
        forkIO $ do
            contents <- recv client 4096
            print contents
            sClose client
```